# How does one diagnose an HTTP 404 for a localhost service call

Tags: wcf, iis, wcf-binding

I am working on a Windows 10 workstation invoking a localhost-hosted service.   I am getting a 404.0 response.  I have verified the following:

- The Physical Path directory is writable by the credentials of the associated application pool
- The application pool pipeline mode is "Classic" and start mode is
  "AlwaysRunning"
- I can confirm that the service does initialize on first call after iisreset.
- I have enabled failed request logging and seen those logs.  They are
  not helpful.
- The 404 error screen says that the handler involved is svc-ISAPI-4.0_32bit
- The URL is an HTTP protocol (not SSL)
- The item under the site is configured as an application, not a
  virtual directory.
- "http" is the single enabled protocol at the application level and the site
  level
- The site is not "Default Web Site" but is mapped to 127.0.0.1
- This same application on the same workstation has worked in the past but that was a while ago
- IIS Version is 10.0.19041.1

I have tried all sorts of theories but nothing explains the 404.0.   Any ideas on where to look next?  Have I hit a known issue with this handler?

Comment: Please try not to misuse tags. SVC is clearly WCF related, so using ASP.NET MVC tag is wrong. Besides, enable WCF tracing to learn more https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/configuring-tracing

Comment: In addition, you can also use the Event Viewer or use the developer tool F12 to check whether there are related error messages in the console.

Comment: @samwu The service supports a SOAP API and is, therefore, not usable via a browser.   We use Postman to invoke it outside of a programming environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered my issue.   It was in the bindings definition.   Since I am working on a local workstation, I am not using SSL.   I neglected to change the `security` mode within the `basicHttpBinding` element in the web.config.  Changing it from "Transport" to "None" did the trick.